# How to align the center of a box with the left edge of another box?

Tags: android, layout, alignment, center, android-relativelayout

[Image of what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5CvH.png)

I want to align the center of the smaller red box to the left-edge of the black box. The red box has it's width and height set to wrap_content and there is a text-view inside. The black box takes up half the screen width. It's in a linear-layout with a spacer on the left and right, the spacers have .25 weight while the black-box has .5 weight.

I'd prefer to do this in XML *without the use of margins*. The red-box may contain 2 characters or 20, the contents come from the server.

There's only "toLeftOf" and "alignLeft". What I want to do is essentially "align center of box to left edge of another box".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation of what you want using only XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />
```

Comment: This uses margins implying the size is known before hand.

Comment: The text that will be in the boxes may be 2 characters or 20, I can't use margins.

Comment: can you post a copy of your current XML, i can base my answer on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xml for your purpose. But what you want center of black box with dynamic content, but it's not recommended, the reason is, if Content too long or too short, it will not look good in UI, because You want to maintain width of red box dynamically as well as center of left edge also. So black box size also you need to change everytime. That is not good. Please try my solution and you can always modify this layout as per your thought process.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="#000000" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/view_1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#ff0000">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will help you !